# filtering out duplicates in rows based on columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

say i have 2 columns:

```
Fruit Condition
apple   unripe
banana  ripe
apple   ripe
banana  moldy
peach   moldy
peach   ripe
apple   ripe
pineapple soldout
```

and i only want to know which fruit are either Ripe or Unripe and not moldy or sold out (only apple)

```
Select fruit
from example
where (condition <> 'moldy' or condition <> 'soldout')
and (condition = 'ripe' or condition = 'unripe')
group by fruit
```

is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `or` in a not. This is the wrong approach for this.

Use:

`where not (condition = 'moldy' or condition = 'soldout')`

or use

`where (condition <> 'moldy' and condition <> 'soldout')`

Then, I assume you want the fruits that are ONLY ripe or unripe.

```
select distinct Fruit
from Example E1
where Condition in ('ripe','unripe')
and not exists 
    (
    select E2.Fruit 
    from Example E2 
    where E1.Fruit = E2.Fruit
    and E2.Condition in ('moldy','soldout')
    )
```

Comment: this is true but it still doesnt fix my situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HAVING` clause with `CASE EXPRESSION` for this purpose :

```
SELECT t.fruit FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.fruit
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.condition in ('ripe','unripe') THEN 1 END) > 0
        -- makes sure at least 1 attribute of ripe/unripe exists
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN t.condition in ('soldout','moldy') THEN 1 END) = 0
        -- makes sure no attribute of soldout/moldy exists
```

Comment: thank you and i would think that this would work but it says i am missing a key word by the ">" symbol

Comment: You have put your `HAVING` operators inside your `CASE` in error

Comment: this still doesnt work for me, it returns no results

Comment: That's weird, don't know what I'm missing. `apple` should be returned .

Comment: @sagi What you're after is `COUNT(case ... end )` not `SUM(case ... end)` - the former returns 0 if it finds no rows meeting the condition, whereas the latter returns null. Fix that, and this answer is what will get my vote!

Comment: :O Silly me.. don't know how I missed that . Thanks . @Boneist

Comment: @Sagi No problemo! It's an easy thing to miss. Thinking about it, you could have stuck with SUMs, but changed the `= 0` to `is null`. One way or t'other, it'd work *{:-) I'd argue that COUNT makes more "logical" sense than SUM, but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select distinct fruit from example where fruit not in
(
select fruit from example 
where condition in ('soldout', 'moldy')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
with example as
    ( select 'apple' as fruit, 'unripe' as condition from dual union all
      select 'banana',    'ripe' from dual union all
      select 'apple',     'ripe' from dual union all
      select 'banana',    'moldy' from dual union all
      select 'peach',     'moldy' from dual union all
      select 'peach',     'ripe' from dual union all
      select 'apple',     'ripe' from dual union all
      select 'pineapple', 'soldout' from dual )
select fruit from example
where  condition in ('ripe','unripe')
minus
select fruit from example
where  condition in ('moldy','soldout');
```